# Hit testing with new UIElements

Tags: .net, wpf, hittest, uielement

I am creating a WPF-usercontrol that needs to check that new UIElements does not overlap with any existing UIElements. The code below works fine when the baseRectangle is added to canvas before the call to button1_Click, but if the rectangle is added in the button1_Click method the hittest does not work.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCollisionTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Height="246" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479"></Canvas>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,264,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>


 public MainWindow()
 { 
     InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     canvas1.Children.Clear();
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
     rect.Width = 200;
     rect.Height = 200;
     rect.Fill = Brushes.Red;
     canvas1.Children.Add(rect);
     if (VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(canvas1, new Point(100, 100)) != null)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Collision");
     }
 }
```

Comment: The control has to be rendered before you can hit-test it. Perhaps run your hit-test at a lower dispatcher priority than `Render`

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I need to add dozens of objects that require hittesting. Is there any way to do the hittesting "manually" before the rendering ? I need to do the hittests agaist a bunch of TextBlocks that I have in an separate collection if that is any help.

Comment: Without having tested that: try adding `canvas1.UpdateLayout();` just before your hit testing code. It's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling canvas1.UpdateLayout() before the hittest solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after adding the rect to the canvas:

```
canvas1.Children.Add(rect);
rect.LayoutUpdated += (s, args) =>
{
    if (VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(canvas1, new Point(100, 100)) != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Collision");
    }
};
```

Of course, that would be hit each time the layout of rect is updated... so you may want to remove the handler, or do some further check inside it.